# An isomorphism of unimodular lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices, lattices-in-lie-groups

In the proof that $SL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a lattice in $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, the following isomorphism is used $$SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})/SL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \{\text{unimodular lattices in } \mathbb{R}^n \text{ with covolume 1} \}$$

<sup>(for example, See proof of theorem 17 in section 2.2.1 [here](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Elee/SebastianSS16.pdf))</sup>

The covolume of a (full-rank) lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $|\text{det}B|$ of its basis  $B$. This is well-defined, since any two bases of the same lattice are related by a unimodular transformation (with determinant $+1$ or $-1$).

Now I am confused, because a lattice having covolume $1$ doesn't imply that it has a basis in $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, it's possible that it only has a negatively-oriented basis with determinant $-1$ instead. So the "isomorphism" doesn't seem to be surjective. Another thing, why take the quotient with $SL_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ when it's possible that two bases of the same lattice are related by unimodular matrix with determinant $-1$, this still would preserve the covolume since we are taking the absolute value.

Is the definition of the covolume incorrect? It doesn't care about the orientation, while the matrix spaces are specifically orientation preserving..

Any clarification would be great!

Comment: It is not clear what you do and what you do not know about lattices of Lie groups, so it is impossible to coherently answer your question. You should add more "context" to the question.

Comment: It is obvious that every lattice has a basis with positive determinant. I don't know the name of the subgroup $G$ of $GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ of matrices with deterinant $\pm1$., but yes the lattices with covolume 1 correspond naturally to $G/GL_n(\Bbb{Z})$ and a bit less naturally to $SL_n(\Bbb{R})/SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$

Comment: Yes, I see it now, we multiply a negatively-oriented basis with a matrix in $\mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ with det $-1$. But then, do we need to restrict to unimodular lattices at all? If the map $\text{det}: \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective, then we don't and the right side of isomorphism could be all lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @mike: The map $\det:\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is not surjective!  Its image is only $\mathbb{Z}$ (and if you restrict to invertible matrices, only $\pm 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a basis $B$ for a unimodular lattice with $\det(B)=-1$, you can just negate one of the terms of $B$ to get a basis $B'$ for the same lattice with $\det(B')=1$.  So, every unimodular lattice can be represented by a basis in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  Moreover, given two elements of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ that represent the same unimodular lattice, the change of basis matrix between them is in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ (since it is a composition of two matrices of determinant $1$).  So, the set of unimodular lattices is in bijection with the coset space $SL_n(\mathbb{R})/SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

(It is also in bijection with $SL^\pm_n(\mathbb{R})/SL^{\pm}_n(\mathbb{Z})=SL^\pm_n(\mathbb{R})/GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ where $SL^\pm$ denotes the group of matrices with determinant $\pm 1$, since you could instead consider arbitrary bases with determinant $\pm 1$ and then the change of basis between two such bases could have determinant either $1$ or $-1$.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! yes, I figured it out, please check comment under original post.